# Bug report ExtJS 7.4.0 Ext.data.reader.Json

Tags: json, extjs, reader, extjs7, jsonreader

first post on this account, how exciting. Sadly, the contents are less exciting. I have found a very simple bug in the `reader.json` function `getResponseData`.

I want to have proper error handling in my application should, unexpectedly, the server I'm querying not provide me with valid JSON. The reader has an exception event for exactly this problem. However, `reader.json` sets `responseType` on the XHR to `"json"`.

And as detailed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType), this results in a `null` value in `response.response` on the XHR:

> When setting responseType to a particular value, the author should make sure that the server is actually sending a response compatible with that format. If the server returns data that is not compatible with the responseType that was set, the value of response will be null.

`getResponseData` wants to avoid work, and so will return `responseJson`, if this is an object:

```
if (typeof response.responseJson === 'object') {
    return response.responseJson;
}
```

However, in the version of Chrome I'm using `typeof null` evaluates to `"object"`.

I fixed this in my application by overriding the function and replacing the first line above with `if (Ext.isObject(response.responseJson)) {`, but I think this should be fixed in the framework code.

I'm not really looking for an answer, but some kind of reaction for sencha would be nice.

This is posted here, because I skimmed over https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/30/why-sencha-is-moving-its-support-forums-to-stack-overflow/

Version information

- ExtJS release version 7.4.0
- Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (64-Bit)

EDIT:
It appears my text was not explicit enough about my problem, so I'll add an example here. I have a store that looks similar to this:

```
Ext.define('myCoolStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.Object.merge({
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                withCredentials: true,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'results'
                },
                listeners: {
                    exception: {
                        fn: me.onAjaxException,
                        scope: me
                    }
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    },

    onAjaxException: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
        // ..
    }
});
```

Now, if I do `myCoolStore.load()`, I expect a server response like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "deprecated": false,
    "results": [{
        "id": "11730",
        "bericht_id": "167",
        "projekt_id": "1429",
        "lastedit": "2021-08-10 16:01:20",
        "lastedit_mitarbeiter_id": "182"
    }],
    "errors": [],
    "messages": [],
    "total": 1,
    "metaData": null
}
```

However, the server might be bugged and return something else, that is invalid JSON. For the sake of simplicity, let's say someone forgot to turn of display_errors in his PHP ini, and the answer looks like this

```
[..date..] [php7:notice] [pid ..pid..] [client ..ip..] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'myCoolProperty' of non-object in file.class.php on line 80, referer: ..myCoolSite..
{
    "success": true,
    "deprecated": false,
    "results": [{
        "id": "11730",
        "bericht_id": "167",
        "projekt_id": "1429",
        "lastedit": "2021-08-10 16:01:20",
        "lastedit_mitarbeiter_id": "182"
    }],
    "errors": [],
    "messages": [],
    "total": 1,
    "metaData": null
}
```

The default behaviour of the `reader.json` will not set an exception here, because the XHR will not be able to parse this, resulting in `reponseJson` being `null`, which will pass the `typeof`-check.

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) specification, `null` is a valid JSON value:

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
> the following three literal names:
>
> false null true

So I think this is the intended behaviour and not a bug. If you want to customize how responses are handled you can try one of the following two methods.

**1. Define a global request exception handler**

Do something like this in your `Application.js`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        const me = this;
        Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', me.onRequestException);
    },
    onRequestException: function (conn, response, options, eOpts) {
        // this will run on every error during request (timeout, abort, 4xx, 5xx etc.)
        // for example Ext.isEmpty(response.responseJson) will result true on null value
        // add a breakpoint here and look what is in the variables in your case
    }
});
```

**2. Create a custom reader to intercept how response is converted**

Define the reader something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.data.reader.RestJson', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    alias: 'reader.myreader',
    getResponseData: function (response) {
        // evalutate here with debugger what you have in
        // response and do the conversion you'd like
        return something;
    }
});
```

And use this reader whenever you need:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'MyModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : 'myurl',
        reader: {
            type: 'myreader'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but you are slightly missing the point here. I have added an example to my post, to be more explicit. `null` may be a valid JSON, but I am concerned with actually invalid JSON, which the XHR will evaluate to `null`. `reader.json` ignores this error state, because it tries to save work.

Comment: @FrankMetis I created a test. I return `(((())` which is an invalid JSON to ExtJS from an API endpoint.  As I wrote in the answer, I added a custom reader. In `getResponseData` function `response.responseJson` is still `(((())` because it is not decoded yet. So you can use `Ext.decode(response.responseJson)` in a `try-catch` block, and then you can intercept invalid JSON, and return the decoded when it is valid.